# What is the reason for Back-off restarting failed container for elasticsearch kubernetes pod?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes

When I try to run my elasticsearch container through kubernetes deployments, my elasticsearch pod fails after some time, While it runs perfectly fine when directly run as docker container using docker-compose or Dockerfile. This is what I get as a result of `kubectl get pods`

```
NAME                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
es-764bd45bb6-w4ckn   0/1       Error     4          3m
```

below is the result of `kubectl describe pod`

```
Name:           es-764bd45bb6-w4ckn
Namespace:      default
Node:           administrator-thinkpad-l480/<node_ip>
Start Time:     Thu, 30 Aug 2018 16:38:08 +0530
Labels:         io.kompose.service=es
            pod-template-hash=3206801662
Annotations:    <none> 
Status:         Running
IP:             10.32.0.8
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/es-764bd45bb6
Containers:
es:
Container ID:   docker://9be2f7d6eb5d7793908852423716152b8cefa22ee2bb06fbbe69faee6f6aa3c3
Image:          docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
Image ID:       docker-pullable://docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch@sha256:9ae20c753f18e27d1dd167b8675ba95de20b1f1ae5999aae5077fa2daf38919e
Port:           9200/TCP
State:          Waiting
  Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
Last State:     Terminated
  Reason:       Error
  Exit Code:    78
  Started:      Thu, 30 Aug 2018 16:42:56 +0530
  Finished:     Thu, 30 Aug 2018 16:43:07 +0530
Ready:          False
Restart Count:  5
Environment:
  ELASTICSEARCH_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME:  es
  ES_JAVA_OPTS:                        -Xms2g -Xmx2g
  ES_HEAP_SIZE:                        2GB
Mounts:
  /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-nhb9z (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-nhb9z:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-nhb9z
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From           Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----           -------
 Normal   Scheduled  6m                default-scheduler                     Successfully assigned default/es-764bd45bb6-w4ckn to administrator-thinkpad-l480
 Normal   Pulled     3m (x5 over 6m)   kubelet, administrator-thinkpad-l480  Container image "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4" already present on machine
 Normal   Created    3m (x5 over 6m)   kubelet, administrator-thinkpad-l480  Created container
 Normal   Started    3m (x5 over 6m)   kubelet, administrator-thinkpad-l480  Started container
 Warning  BackOff    1m (x15 over 5m)  kubelet, administrator-thinkpad-l480  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Here is my elasticsearc-deployment.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.1.0 (36652f6)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: es
  name: es
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: es
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
          value: es
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms2g -Xmx2g
        - name: ES_HEAP_SIZE
          value: 2GB
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
        name: es
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
 status: {}
```

When i try to get logs using `kubectl logs -f es-764bd45bb6-w4ckn`, I get

```
Error from server: Get https://<slave node ip>:10250/containerLogs/default/es-764bd45bb6-w4ckn/es?previous=true: dial tcp <slave node ip>:10250: i/o timeout
```

What could be the reason and solution for this problem ?

Comment: try print out some logs, I don't see that much info through the pod describe.

Comment: @Tim .. i get this response when i try to get logs 
Error from server: Get https://<slave node ip>:10250/containerLogs/default/es-764bd45bb6-w4ckn/es?previous=true: dial tcp <slave node ip>:10250: i/o timeout

Comment: Please update your question with the output from `kubectl logs -f es-764bd45bb6-w4ckn`

Comment: @UroshT. already did.

Comment: can you see something from this: kubectl logs -f <yourpod> --previous

Comment: @Tim no, the output is same as kubectl logs -f <podname>

Comment: apiserver tried to connect the kubelet of the host that is running the es pod, but failed, you can login into the host and use command `docker logs` to get the logs.

Comment: See if this helps https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4891

Comment: @KunLi it worked thanks.. though it is a workaround and i am able to see the logs. could you explain why i am not able to see the logs through kubectl logs command ?

Comment: @HarshalShah naah ... didn't help

Comment: @Lakshya slave node is abnormal, I suppose, kubelet is not listening at 10250 port ? check the log of kubelet for more detail.

Comment: @KunLi yeah kubelet is not listening on port 10250 but there is no reason showing for that in logs either.

Comment: CrashLoopBackOff just means the pod keeps crashing and k8s has given up on it. You need to determine what is causing the crash. You can use "watch kubectl describe [pod_name]" to view events as the pod is being created, this is useful if there is an issue during creation. If the pod crashes after it starts up, you'll need to get the container logs, which you can get using docker as mentioned above.

Comment: We had similar issue with es, sometimes not starting properly. It was diagnosed to be tied to liveness/readiness probe, since reloading of indexes took too much time and pod was deemed not ready mid-flight and restarted. Tweaking of probes parameters (initialDelaySeconds and such, see [Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/)) to postpone probes until index is properly loaded helped in our case, can you give it a go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the logs using `docker logs` for the es container and found that es was not starting because of the `vm.max_map_count` set to very low value.
I changed the `vm.max_map_count` to desired value using `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` and the pod has started after that.

Comment: sysctl: unknown oid 'vm.max_map_count'

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem, there can be couple of reasons for this issue. In my case the jar file was missing. @Lakshya has already answered this problem, I would like to add the steps that you can take to troubleshoot it.

1. Get the pod status, Command - **kubectl get pods**
2. Describe pod to have further look - **kubectl describe pod "pod-name"**
   The last few lines of output gives you events and where your deployment failed
3. Get logs for more details - **kubectl logs "pod-name"**
4. Get container logs - **kubectl logs "pod-name" -c "container-name"**
   Get the container name from the output of describe pod command

If your container is up, you can use the **kubectl exec -it** command to further analyse the container

Hope it helps community members in future issues.

Comment: thanks. I guess you did not notice that I have answered my own question lately when I found the solution. Nevertheless, the steps above might help people in future.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just run `kubectl run ubuntu --image=ubuntu` get similar err and `kubectl logs` is empty

I guess the reason is ubuntu image without command will auto poweroff, so the solution is:

output k8s ubuntu conf yaml

in command make container command with don't container poweroff(for ex, add "sleep infinity", following is work conf yaml

```
{
  "kind": "Pod",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "ubuntu",
    "creationTimestamp": null,
    "labels": {
      "run": "ubuntu"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "ubuntu",
        "image": "ubuntu:20.04",
        "command": [
          "sleep",
          "infinity"
        ],
        "resources": {},
        "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
      }
    ],
    "restartPolicy": "Always"
  },
  "status": {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it was simple memory issue as many pods were running. i deleted old pods and able to run new deployment

Comment: I dont think this will help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe config incorrect but valid, read pod logs and find error message. Fix configs and redeploy app